# How is it the Voyagers are a few seconds closer to Earth than earlier?

Tags: astronomy, space-mission

The [Voyager 2 tweet](https://twitter.com/NASAVoyager2/status/307641955930738691) of March 01, 2013 put it's distance at 14 hrs 04 mins 23 secs of light-travel time from Earth. A [more recent](https://twitter.com/NASAVoyager2/status/308004276901392384) (earlier today) tweet says it is 14 hrs 04 mins 22 secs of light-travel time from Earth. An [older](https://twitter.com/NASAVoyager2/status/307279564785192960) tweet put it still further out at 14 hrs 04 mins 25 secs of light-travel time.

The Voyager 2 tweets on Voyager 1's proximity to Earth too has reduced similarly to [17 hrs 07 mins 07 secs of light-travel time](https://twitter.com/NASAVoyager2/status/307823054153723904) earlier today from [17 hrs 07 mins 11 secs of light-travel time](https://twitter.com/NASAVoyager2/status/307098310085316609) reported on Feb 28 2013

It could quite simply be a typo ... If not a typo then my curiosity is piqued; I was under the impression the Voyagers are outbound from the Solar System now without any major in-system activities now.

How is it the Voyagers are closer to Earth than before?

Comment: It might be that the Earth's orbit around the Sun means that at certain times of year it's moving towards the Voyagers faster than they're moving away from it. I'd be interested to know if that's the case.

Comment: @Nathaniel it is the case. You're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Note: Because Earth moves around the sun faster than Voyager 1 is traveling from Earth, the distance between Earth and the spacecraft actually decreases at certain times of the year. "
- quoted from http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/where/index.html

[image]